# Why does "use strict" not respect variable scope

Tags: javascript, strict

I have a question regarding the usage of "use strict" variables.

Why does the following fail silently instead of throwing an error?

```
"use strict"; 
var $class = {};
$class.rowsICanDisplay = 10;
$class.difference = -1;
var absDifference = 1;
var gridTableBody = $('#mytable tbody');
//code removed for clarity
if($class.difference > 0) {
    var offset = $class.rowsICanDisplay - absDifference; // mistake should be declared in outer scope
    //code removed for clarity
    $('tr:lt(' + offset + ')', gridTableBody).remove();
}
else {
     //code removed for clarity
     $('tr:gt(' + offset + ')', gridTableBody).remove(); // why does this fail silently
}
```

Comment: Because Javascript doesn't have block scope.  Sorry.  JSHint will catch that, though.

Comment: @EricHerlitz - sorry fixed that (wasn't actually a problem in the actual code).

Comment: @SLaks - ah I see, thats rather frustrating since it appears like it does. I guess I'll make a post build task to run JSHint then thankyou. (if you write this as an answer I'll make it the selected one)

Comment: JavaScript scope is functional. Outer scope variables are available in the outer scope and they are available to any functions within that scope.

Comment: As a side note, I would suggest you avoid using $ in front of your variable names. That's more of a PHP thing and it can easily be confused with jQuery.

Comment: ah its just there because class is a reserved word, perhaph's calling it thisClass would be better do you think? since in my actual code base its a pointer to a function which is being used a class...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because Javascript doesn't have block scope.
Any variable declared anywhere in a function is visible to the entire function.

JSHint will catch this problem.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('tr:gt(' + offset + ')', gridTableBody).remove(); // why does this fail silently
```

Because `offset` is not defined in the context of your `else` block, so your selector is invalid and isn't matching anything.

Comment: But it shouldn't it throw an error because it isn't defined because of use strict is supposed to protect against use of undefined variables.

Comment: The `var offfset = ...` defines the variable globally so the else sees that it is _defined_ although the value will be "undefined".

Comment: only javascript could have a defined variable with a value of undefined... if thats not confusing terminology idk what is, it also begs the question of what to call a variable a variable which isn't defined (by that I mean without a var x = ...;.

Comment: @AlexisWilke The distinction you're pointing out is meaningless in terms of JavaScript, there's no way to distinguish between a declared-but-undefined variable and an undeclared variable. `typeof offset` will result in `"undefined"` in the else block.

Comment: @Madbreaks, if you read SLaks answer, you'll see that what I'm saying is not completely off target. A "var" _instruction_ "defines" the variable for that function (or in the global scope of you're not in a function) whether it gets assigned a value or not and wherever it appears in the function. This is why the "user strict" doesn't react. The best is to declare all your variables at the top like in C.

Answer (score 1):

In the else statement, offset is not defined. You need to pull it out and define it outside of the "if" structure.

Comment: This is incorrect. There's no block scoping in JavaScript; it's different in that regard from Java and C++. All `var` statements are treated as if they appeared at the top of the function.

Comment: Yes I realize that, but in order for it to be defined when it hits the else statement, he needs to pull it out. I'm not saying that a new scope is applied, but rather he needs to pull it in to a spot that would give that variable a definition prior to usage :p

Comment: Oh right; I see what you're saying. It's not *incorrect* by strict mode, but it's incorrect because the `var` initialization expression isn't run in the `else` branch!